# How to get a list of video URLs from a specific YouTube channel

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get a list of video URLs from a specific YouTube channel with Python.

First, I wrote the following code.

```
import os
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd

API_KEY = os.environ['API_KEY']
CHANNEL_ID = 'your_searching_channel_id'

base_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3'
url = base_url + '/search?key=%s&channelId=%s&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50'
infos = []
```

But I don't know the next step.

I read YouTube API HELP, but I couldn't understand how to structure the program.

Comment: _But I dnot know next step. I read YouTube API HELP,　couldn't understand how to structure the program._ Can you be more specific? Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials, or documentation, by the way. See: [help/on-topic], [ask], [tour].

Answer (score 8):

Logic ->

**Import Necessary libraries.**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

**Use Selenium.**
I'm picking up Chrome driver.Make sure your chromedriver is in same directory in which you are running the script.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

**Supply the Youtube Channel's url.**

```
url = input("Enter Youtube Channel URL : ")
```

**Go to the videos section.**

```
driver.get(url+"/videos")
```

**Scroll down till the end of the page.**
Because the page loads when scrolled down,we need to take care of this.

```
ht=driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")
while True:
    prev_ht=driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)
    ht=driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")
    if prev_ht==ht:
        break
```

**Find links of all the videos.**

```
links=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="video-title"]')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

That's it.

Cons- Requires a webdriver. Slower than getting results directly from Youtube API.

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided assumes that the link given to driver.get() is a Youtube Playlist. Modify it at your discretion.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("pathToChromeDriver")
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WN-IW6wOdnI&list=PLs4hTtftqnlBOsOiQ2U1fddASTO9SlRbY')

def collectLinks():
    elements = []
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
    print("Collecting links...")
    for elem in elems:
        elements.append(str(elem.get_attribute("href")))

    for i in elements:
        print(i)

collectLinks()
driver.quit()
```

Where "pathToChromeDriver" is replaced by your path to chrome driver.

Where 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WN-IW6wOdnI&list=PLs4hTtftqnlBOsOiQ2U1fddASTO9SlRbY' is replaced by the playlist you want to find all url links.